как правильно заполнить Thread Group в JMeter
как правильно заполнить параметры Thread Group для нагрузочного теста в JMeter. допустим нужно каждую секунду отправлять по 10 запросов в течение 30 минут.
тогда

Number of Thread=10;
ramp-up=1;
loop count=infinite;
duration = 1800;

поправьте пожалуйста если неправильно, или другие параметры нужно включить?

Используйте Precise Throughput Timer

Насчет Number of Thread=10 - вы сможете добиться 10 запросов в секунду только если время отклика будет равно одной секунде (или меньше), если тестируемая система обрабатывает запросы медленнее - количество запросов в секунду будет соответственно меньше
Если вам нужно добиться X запросов в секунду - самое простое решение использовать комбинацию Throughput Shaping Timer и Concurrency Thread Group, если вы укажете количество виртуальных пользователей с помощью Feedback Function то JMeter сможет запускать новые потоки если текущее количество недостаточно для генерации желаемой нагрузки
